# WiX Create an Annoying Feature?

Tags: audio, wix

During install, I would like to play a .wav or .mp3 (using Media Player I suppose, or anything else 'hidden' from the regular desktop) to mess with a dev-tester's mind. Any suggestions on how I can make this possible with WiX 3.5?

Thanks.

Comment: what if media player is uninstalled? I dont think this is a good option

Comment: You don't think "what" is a good option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know WIX doesn't have direct support for this. You will have to write your own custom action.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_customaction.htm